# Adding image for a button using content.js in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add a button to a webpage using `content.js` in Chrome extensions but I end up with the source image not being loaded. Here is my `content.js` code:

```
var confirmButton = document.createElement('div');
    confirmButton.innerHTML = '<button><img src="../images/logo_balloon.png" /></button>';
    document.body.appendChild(confirmButton);
```

When I check developer mode and inspect the button, after hovering over the image source the below link appears:

`https://www.example.com/images/logo_balloon.png`

I created and HTML file and copied the code above and image showed up there. Where am I making a mistake? Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert a relative path within an app/extension install directory to a fully qualified URL, you can use

```
const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('./your-relative-path-here');
```

But in this case you probably need to mark this asset as a web accesssible resource in the manifest file (see details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/)).

The other option (simplest one, I think) is to convert your image to Base64. Plenty of encoders are available online

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,aBVORw..." />
```